# How can I use the index of an element in list 1 to change an index in list 2?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, indexing

What code would I use to lookup the index values of **guess** in **lettersInWord** and change those indeces from **'-'** to **guess** in **lettersDisplayed**?

```
guess = 'o'
lettersInWord = ['n', 'o', 'o', 'n']
lettersDisplayed = ['-', '-', '-', '-']
```

Comment: I'm trying to learn Python and I hit a wall on a section of a Hangman program I'm working on. To those who answered, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
guess = 'o'
word, disp = ['n', 'o', 'o', 'n'], ['-', '-', '-', '-']
print [guess if i == guess else j for i, j in zip(word, disp)]
```

**Output**

```
['-', 'o', 'o', '-']
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign a "blank" string (in your case "-") and then use a list comprehension to change the items in place.

```
guess = 'o'
blank = '-'
lettersInWord = ['n', 'o', 'o', 'n']

lettersDisplayed = [guess if x == guess else blank for x in lettersInWord]

print lettersDisplayed # ['-', 'o', 'o', '-']
print ''.join(lettersDisplayed) # -oo-
```

**EDIT:** note that this effectively only works for one "guess" as if you guess again it will ignore your initial guess. If you're looking for multiple guesses then please see jonrsharpe's answer.

Comment: This will switch all the previously-guessed letters back!

Comment: Yes you're right it will if you guess more than once. The poster didn't state whether more than one guess would be made but in that case I think your solution is probably best.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm astonished how quickly I was able to get an answer here!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to keep the previously-revealed letters in `disp` on each `guess`. In that case, you could use:

```
blank = '-'
word = list("noon")
disp = [blank for char in word]
for guess in ['m', 'n', 'o']:
    disp = [w if (d == blank and w == guess) else d 
            for w, d in zip(word, disp)]
    print(guess, disp)
```

This retains previous guesses and reveals the newly-guessed letters.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm astonished how quickly I was able to get an answer here!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple option with some loops:

```
guess = 'o'
lettersInWord = ['n', 'o', 'o', 'n']
lettersDisplayed = ['-', '-', '-', '-']

listOfFinds = []
for idx, value in enumerate(lettersInWord):
    if guess == value:
        listOfFinds.append(idx)

for value in listOfFinds:
    lettersDisplayed[value] = guess

print lettersDisplayed
```

**Output:**

```
['-', 'o', 'o', '-']
```